# Strange .NET CAS client URL encoding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cas

I'm using the .NET CAS Client with ASP.NET MVC, and I have a link to allow the user to log in to SSO and remain on the same page.  The link goes to `/MyApp/Account/SsoLogin?returnUrl=%2fMyApp%2fMyController%2fMyAction%3fFirstParameter%3d12345%26SecondParameter=54321`.  Decoded, `returnUrl` should be `/MyApp/MyController/MyAction?FirstParameter=12334&SecondParameter=54321`

Unfortunately, the raw URL I'm getting in my controller action after CAS is `/Account/SsoLogIn?returnUrl=/MyController/MyAction?FirstParameter&SecondParameter=54321`.

So the return URL has been decoded and the value for the first parameter is gone.  This is for both when someone has already authenticated with SSO and when they haven't yet.  I opened up Firebug to look at what was happening for the case where they've already authenticated.  Here's what I've got:

```
302, location is https://ssoserver/cas/login?service=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a10001%2fMyApp%2fAccount%2fSsoLogIn%3freturnUrl%3d%2fMyApp%2fMyController%2fMyAction%3fFirstParameter%3d12345%26SecondParameter%3d54321
```

Then we have another 302:

```
302, location is http://localhost:10001/MyApp/Account/SsoLogIn?returnUrl=/MyApp/MyController/MyAction?FirstParameter=12345&SecondParameter=54321&ticket=someUglyString
```

Here we first see the two question marks.

Then we have a third 302:

```
302, location is http://localhost:10001/MyApp/Account/SsoLogIn?returnUrl=/MyApp/MyController/MyAction?FirstParameter=12345&SecondParameter=54321
```

More of the double-question mark.  Now the last 302:

```
302, location is /MyApp/MyController/MyAction?FirstParameter&SecondParameter=54321
```

Then we get a 500 error trying to load `/MyApp/MyController/MyAction?FirstParameter&SecondParameter=54321`, which should have been `/MyApp/MyController/MyAction?FirstParameter=12345&SecondParameter=54321`.

Any ideas?